# Android: Html.toHtml() adds html tag on every word

Tags: java, android, html

Html.toHtml() applies tags on every word separately

Original text:
**Hello World**

Html.ToHtml() result:

```
<p dir="ltr"><b>Hello</b><b> </b><b>World</b></p>
```

I want to merge all repeating `<b>` tag into one `<b>` tag.

This is the code I am using to apply span

```
spannable.setSpan(new StyleSpan(typeFace), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
```

using typeFace to `Typeface.BOLD` or `Typeface.ITALIC`

I tried with `Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE`also, still no use.

This is how i applies span in EditText while typing

```
protected void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int lengthBefore, int lengthAfter) {
    super.onTextChanged(text, start, lengthBefore, lengthAfter);
    if (lengthAfter > lengthBefore)
        applyCurrentStyle(start, start + lengthAfter);
}
```

applyCurrentStyle():

```
private void applyCurrentStyle(int startSpan, int endSpan) {
    for (Style style : mCurrentStyles) {
        boolean alreadyHas = false;
        switch (style) {
            case BOLD:
                for (StyleSpan span : getStyleSpans(Typeface.BOLD, startSpan, endSpan)) {
                    if (getText().getSpanEnd(span) == endSpan) {
                        alreadyHas = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!alreadyHas)
                    setStyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD, startSpan, endSpan);
                break;
            case ITALIC:
                for (StyleSpan span : getStyleSpans(Typeface.ITALIC, startSpan, endSpan)) {
                    if (getText().getSpanEnd(span) == endSpan) {
                        alreadyHas = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!alreadyHas)
                    setStyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC, startSpan, endSpan);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, your `StyleSpan` spans both words? Or do you have two `StyleSpan` objects, one per word?

Comment: @CommonsWare No, I am avoiding new StyleSpan if already exist. updated Question with  code.